# Use ShareKit to login to Facebook and use login credentials to view page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, sharekit

I've got a kludgy problem, please bear with me as I try to explain it:
I am working on an iPhone app that allows users to view pictures they have posted by loading a Uiwebview of a URL: https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/foodporn within my app.

I want to have users of my app be able to view this with minimal hassle, the problem is that when I launch the Uiwebview they are forced to sign in to view the foodporn hashtag. Since it is not Safari they must login each time because the credentials are not stored.

I was thinking of using ShareKit to login to facebook, and then I could store the credentials and then pass the login credentials to the Uiwebview.

So my question is this: is it possible to get the stored credentials for Facebook from shareKit and then pass that onto the Uiwebview without having the user login again?

Comment: If that were possible, it would be a horrible security problem. Maybe proxy the Facebook page on your server?

Comment: You must login each time? It a rare behavior, because the UIWebView have your own cookie storage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible, but it was strange for me, that user has to login each time, so I tested it. 
I saw 2 scenarios:
1. Run app from XCode -> Load WebView with Your Link -> Login Required -> Login -> Run app from XCode once more -> Load WebView with Your Link -> Login Required.
2. Run app from XCode -> Load WebView with Your Link -> Login Required -> Login -> **Kill the app from Simulator** -> Run app again from simulator -> Login not Required.

So, make sure that You are not using only first scenario, because it looks like credentials should be stored.

Comment: I notice the same.And if you Run the app-> Load WebView -> Login Requeried -> Login -> Go home -> Run once more -> Load WebView -> Login not Required. It is crazy.